# What Would Happen if CPU Load Average is High

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-load

I read some articles about the CPU load average. They were talking about the definition, the differences between the CPU usage, and the optimal value (roughly equals to the number of cores). They also mentioned that if the number is high, you will be in trouble (waking up at mid-night etc.), but what would actually be happening if the number is high?

For example, I have been running 4, 6 and 8 sessions on a 4 core Linux server. Although the time it took to finish the task were different (4 fasted, 8 slowest), the results seem OK. The CPU load averages were roughly 4, 8 and 10. I understand that 10 might not be a good number, but then what?

Comment: have you tried looking into it why such high numbers? is it a expected behavior due to some heavy Application or are you trying to find the malfunction here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just that: if you run absurdly high load averages, the overall efficiency will suffer: the CPU processing power will go to waste.

This is caused by several factors; the most immediate being more CPU time needed for scheduling the competing tasks. One not at all insignificant factor is that several competing processes will also overutlize the CPU cache; each task switch effectively throwing out the cache contents and replacing them with new ones. Further choke points come in forms of bottlenecks in memory and storage bandwidths.